# sql orderby destroys inner self join query

Tags: mysql, sql

My query works fine without ORDER BY (<1sec). But takes about 20s with it:
I have single column indexes on all columns

```
   SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM file_results data
     INNER JOIN file_result_filters gender ON data.id = gender.file_result_id AND gender.filter = 'filter1' AND gender.value = 'male'
     INNER JOIN file_result_filters age ON data.id = age.file_result_id AND age.filter = 'filter2' AND age.value > 20
     INNER JOIN file_result_filters height ON data.id = height.file_result_id AND height.filter = 'filter3' AND height.value > 150
    ORDER BY age.value DESC
```

file_results table:

```
id, ...
```

file_result_filters:

```
id, file_result_id, filter, value
```

The funny thing is that it works when I only have 2 inner joins instead of 3

Comment: How large are the tables?

Comment: Start by checking the output of EXPLAIN for that statement.

Comment: Trying a delivered table age what filters that filter and age and orders value might force the optimizer in a more optimal execution... And you want a multi columnindex on (filter, value) that should also speed up execution

Answer (score 1):

The reason is based on when MySQL can start returning data.

Without an `ORDER BY`, MySQL can start returning data as soon as any rows match.  It looks like the results are coming in fast.

With an `ORDER BY`, MySQL has to process all the data to find all possible matches.  Results are not returned immediately, but only after the `ORDER BY`.

Of course, the `ORDER BY` itself also takes time, so that is also contributing to the delay.

Comment: It works fine with 2 inner joins and order by. I just found out that it breaks when I add the 3 rd